# How can we convert path.td to array of latitude and longitude in google map api?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps

I am using geolib for calculating the distance of latitude and longitude of polyline but after editing and undoing the line , I am getting the latitude and longitude in different format(u can check console), so I am unable to calculate the distance.

For reference stack blitz URL :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-draw-polygon-google-maps-pkharg?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Please help me in advance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

polyline.getPath returns MVCArray of google.maps.LatLng which has lat lng functions. You need to map this array into lan lng number array

```
_this.coordinates = path.getArray().map((p) => [p.lat(), p.lng()]);
```